# Saving the output file from dataset array for loop in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

A have a number of txt files with data, and names like trhg2110_02, trhg2110_03. I am running a script that includes a "for" loop to manupulate these files and I want each time the output is saved in txt files with the same or similar name.The output of each loop is the `"ut_ROTI"` (see below) which is a dataset array with two columns and rows of data. Could you please tell me how to do this? Thanks- Duarte.

```
myFolder = uigetdir('C:\','Selecione Diretório');
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.txt');
txtfiles   = dir(filePattern);
for k = 1:length(txtfiles)
  baseFileName = txtfiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
  fprintf('Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
  textFilename = sprintf('fullFileName', k);
  fid          = fopen(baseFileName, 'rt');
```

Data Processing...

```
ut_ROTI=dataset({ cellstr(datestr(datenum([hora_minuto,zeros(size(hora_minuto,1),1)]),15)),'UT'}, {ROTI 'ROTI'});
```

I've already tried to use many commands but it didn't work:

```
outfile=['thrg2110_PRN01' int2str(k) '.txt'];
save(outfile,'ut_ROTI','-ascii');
```

The error message is: **Warning: Attempt to write an unsupported data type to an ASCII file. Variable 'ut_ROTI' not written to file.**

Thanks!

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? `dataset` is being deprecated in favor of [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) (introduced in R2013b), which has more robust output methods.

Comment: Hi excaza, I'm using the R2012b version.

Comment: Use [`export`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.export.html)

Comment: I've already tried but the program saves only the last loop, I need to save all loops...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset-arrays.html

Because a dataset array is a unique data type it cannot be directly converted to ascii by the 'save' function.

You will need to convert it before using the 'save' function.  You can convert 'ut_ROTI' to a structure using 'dataset2struct" and then use the '-struct' option with the save function.  Or convert it to a numeric matrix or cell matrix before using 'save'.